# Как изменять текст ссылки при переключении видимости блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма. По умолчанию в ней два инпута 'readonly' и ссылки на возможность изменить значения (Change password и Change email). При клике на эти ссылки выпадает блок с дополнительными полями формы. Это присказка.. Сказка в том, что при раскрытом окошке текст ссылки меняется на крестик, и, соответственно, при клике на крестик должен возвращаться исходный текст (подходящий к своему полю). Не могу понять как мне получать эти значения в самом начале и после клика на крестик подставлять нужное значение. Сейчас пока у меня в лоб прописано одно значение, что для второго инпута получается неверно.

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/169024/

```
$(function() {
    var collapseLink = '[data-toggle=collapse]';

$(collapseLink).on("click", function (e){ 
    $(this).closest(".form-group").toggleClass("collapseBg");
    var collapseToggle = $(this).attr("aria-expanded");

    if (collapseToggle === 'true') {
        $(this).children().html("Change password").removeClass('close')
    } else {
        $(this).children().html("&times;").addClass('close')
    }
});             
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).children().text()` содержит текст нажатой ссылки, но у Вас есть еще несколько вариантов
- добавить два параметра data-close data-show к примеру и подменять с их помощью надпись
- создать сразу две ссылки и тоглить их видимость т.е. показавать одну и скрывать другую при помощь toggle